# How to correctly bind a ViewModel (which Include Separators) to WPF's Menu?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, menuitem

I'm using MVVM and I want to data bind my list of `MenuViewModels` to my maim menu. Which consists of a set of menu items and separators.

Here's my MenuItemViewModel code:

```
public interface IMenuItemViewModel
{
}

[DebuggerDisplay("---")]
public class SeparatorViewModel : IMenuItemViewModel
{
}

[DebuggerDisplay("{Header}, Children={Children.Count}")]
public class MenuItemViewModel : IMenuItemViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MenuItemViewModel(string header, ICommand command, ImageSource imageSource)
    {
        Header = header;
        Command = command;
        ImageSource = imageSource;

        Children = new List<IMenuItemViewModel>();
    }

    public string Header { get; private set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; private set; }

    public ImageSource ImageSource { get; private set; }

    public IList<IMenuItemViewModel> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

And my Main window looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:MenuItemViewModel}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}"
                  Command="{Binding Command}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:SeparatorViewModel}">
        <Separator />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
    </Menu>
</DockPanel>
```

Should be very simple stuff. Unfortunately, either the menu item looks wrong or the separator is an empty `menuItem` (depending on what I've tried).

So, how do I get my `Menu` to find my two `DataTemplates`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Solved my own question**

After spending several hours searching the web, I found lots of examples that work *against* the WPF's natural intentions but none that worked with it.

Here's how to work *with* the `Menu` control and not against it...

**A little Background**

WPF's `Menu` control will *normally* auto create `MenuItem` objects for you when it is binded to a POCO collection, using the `ItemsSource` property.

However, this default behavior **can** be overridden! Here's how...

**The Solution**

First, you must create a class that derives from `ItemContainerTemplateSelector`. Or use the simple class I've created:

```
public class MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector : ItemContainerTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, ItemsControl parentItemsControl)
    {
        var key = new DataTemplateKey(item.GetType());
        return (DataTemplate) parentItemsControl.FindResource(key);
    }
}
```

Second, you must add a reference to the `MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector` class to your Windows `resources` object, like so:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Selectors:MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector x:Key="_menuItemContainerTemplateSelector" />
```

Third, you must set two properties (`UsesItemContainerTemplate`, and `ItemContainerTemplateSelector`) on both the `Menu` and the `MenuItem` (which is defined in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`).

Like so:

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:MenuItemViewModel}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}"
                  Command="{Binding Command}"
                  UsesItemContainerTemplate ="true"
                  ItemContainerTemplateSelector=
                  "{StaticResource _menuItemContainerTemplateSelector}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
          UsesItemContainerTemplate="True"
          ItemContainerTemplateSelector=
          "{StaticResource _menuItemContainerTemplateSelector}">
    </Menu>
```

**Why it Works**

For optimization purposes, the `Menu` uses the `UsesItemContainerTemplate` flag (which has a default value of `false`) to skip the `DataTemplate` lookup and just returns a normal `MenuItem` object. Therefore, we needed to set this value to `true` and then our `ItemContainerTemplateSelector` works as expected.

Happy Coding!

Comment: I am getting "Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended" on parentItemsControl.FindResource() for the separator. Without separator everything works fine. Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: For anybody using this solution with sub menus, make sure to set `ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"` in your `MenuItem`. Simply settings it on `HierarchialDataTemplate` doesn't do the trick... Great tips here though thank you!

Answer (score 4):

A solution without the TemplateSelector:

provide ItemContainerTemplates instead of the DataTemplates      :

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}" UsesItemContainerTemplate="True">
              <ContextMenu.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                  <ItemContainerTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:MenuItemViewModel }">
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Header}" Command="{Binding Path=Command}" UsesItemContainerTemplate="True">
                      <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}"/>
                      </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                  </ItemContainerTemplate>
                  <ItemContainerTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:SeparatorViewModel}">
                    <Separator >
                      <Separator.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}}"/>
                      </Separator.Style>
                    </Separator>
                  </ItemContainerTemplate>
                </ResourceDictionary>
              </ContextMenu.Resources>
            </ContextMenu>
```

Notes:

- I haven't tried Children
- the separator [styled wrong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749214(v=vs.85).aspx): I had to manually re-apply the style

Comment: I'm creating a new project, so I decided to try your approach since it is simple, but WPF (in .net 6) rendered my sub-MenuItems at the top of the screen. So I had to go back to my original implementation - which, thankfully worked.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to:

- have a Boolean property on your menu item ViewModel that indicates whether an item is a separator or not
- use a trigger based on this property to change the `ControlTemplate` of the `MenuItem` so that it uses a `Separator` control instead

Like so:

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSeparator}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                <Separator />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:MenuItemViewModel}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" />
    </Menu.Resources>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Adding the DataTrigger with the IsSeparator Property solved it.